# Accordion Keyboard layout with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees, tikz-cd, keyboard

I am trying to draw accordion keyboard layout with Tikz To have results like this with modified variable, Could someone helps me to create something similar with Tikz ? Does anyone have any code exemple close to this ? :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Could someone helps me to create something similar with Tikz ? Does anyone have any code exemple close to this ?

I am really new in Programmation and I thanks you by advance for your help !

[1]:

Answer (score 3):

Here is my attempt at creating the seemingly evenly placed array of circles on the right image:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{musicography}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.multipart}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    mycirc/.style={%
        draw,circle split,
        minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm
    },
    accord/.style={mycirc},
    basse/.style={mycirc,very thick}
]
    \matrix[%
        matrix of nodes,
        every node/.style={anchor=center},
        every odd row/.style={nodes={accord}},
        every even row/.style={nodes={basse}},
        row sep=5mm,column sep=5mm
    ]{%
        maj\nodepart{lower}min
        & maj\nodepart{lower}maj
        & maj\nodepart{lower}min
        \\
        SI\nodepart{lower}DO\sh
        & MI\fl\nodepart{lower}SI\fl
        & SOL\sh\nodepart{lower}SI
        \\

        maj\nodepart{lower}min
        & maj\nodepart{lower}min
        & maj\nodepart{lower}maj
        \\
        LA\nodepart{lower}FA\sh
        & MI\fl\nodepart{lower}LA
        & SOL\sh\nodepart{lower}RE
        \\

        maj\nodepart{lower}maj
        & |[circle,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm]|
          maj
        & maj\nodepart{lower}maj
        \\
        RE\nodepart{lower}DO
        & |[circle,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm]|
          FA
        & DO\sh\nodepart{lower}SOL
        \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

### Explanation

Right after `\begin{tikzpicture}` I define some styles:

- `mycirc` is just a split circle with some minimal specified dimensions (so that the circles are evenly sized)
- `accord` and `basse` are just extensions: `accord` adds nothing extra and just acts as an alias but `basse` also makes the shape `very thick`

I then use a `matrix` to easily create all the `accord` and `basse` nodes. Note that you do not have to use the `every odd/even row` part, it just avoids explicitly specifying the style to use for each element of the matrix.

I hope this helps a little.
You can do something similar with the keyboard on the left, but that requires some more advanced positioning (possibly with something other than a matrix).

---

**UPDATE 2020-12-01:** Here is another `tikzpicture` that draws the left image. It uses the `chains` library instead of a matrix and some loops to avoid writing out all the `node`s. There is definitely room for improvements (for example to avoid writing out all the numbers in the loop), but this is what I got so far.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{musicography}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning,shapes.multipart}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    node distance=2mm,
    accord/.style={%
        draw,circle split,anchor=center,
        minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1.5cm
    },
    lb/.style={%
        font={\scriptsize},gray,
        label distance=-2mm,xshift=-7.5mm
    },
    start chain=1 going below,
    start chain=2 going below,
    start chain=3 going below,
]
    \node[%
        accord,on chain=1,label={[lb]above:1}
    ] (L) {DO\sh\nodepart{lower}MI\fl};
    \foreach \t/\b/\n in {%
        RÉ/FA\sh/2,SOL/LA/3,SI/DO/4,RÉ/MI/5,SOL/FA\sh/6,
        SI/LA/7,RÉ/DO/8,SOL/MI/9,SI/FA\sh/10,RÉ/LA\sh/11,
        SOL/DO/12
    } \node[%
        accord,on chain=1,label={[lb]above:\n}
    ] {\t\nodepart{lower}\b};

    \node[%
        accord,on chain=2,below right=-2.5mm and 8mm of L,
        label={[lb]above:{1'}}
    ] (M) {LA\nodepart{lower}SOL\sh};
    \foreach \t/\b/\n in {%
        SOL/SI/2,DO/RÉ/3,MI/FA/4,SOL/LA/5,DO/SI/6,MI/RÉ/7,
        SOL/FA/8,DO/LA/9,MI/SI/10,SOL/RÉ/11
    } \node[%
        accord,on chain=2,label={[lb]above:{\n'}}
    ] {\t\nodepart{lower}\b};

    \node[%
        accord,on chain=3,below right=-2.5mm and 8mm of M,
        label={[lb]above:{1''}}
    ] {SOL\sh\nodepart{lower}SI\fl};
    \foreach \t/\b/\n in {%
        SI\fl/DO\sh/2,MI\fl/SOL/3,SOL\sh/SOL\sh/4,SI\fl/SI\fl/5,
        MI\fl/DO\sh/6,SOL\sh/SOL/7,SI\fl/SOL\sh/8,MI\fl/SI\fl/9,
        SOL\sh/DO\sh/10
    } \node[%
        accord,on chain=3,label={[lb]above:{\n''}}
    ] {\t\nodepart{lower}\b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code for image on the left]

---

**UPDATE 2021-03-28:** The following is one way to arrange the whole thing.

Create all four figures in separate documents (I named these `top.tex`, `left.tex`, `right.tex`, and `bottom.tex`), all using the `standalone` document class. You can now remove the `border` option from the beginning of each of these, it was only for aesthetic purposes when the figures were rendered separately. The `standalone` *package* (there is a documentclass and a package as well) allows you to simply do eg. `\input{top}` to add the output of the standalone document named `top.tex`.

Now all you need to do is arrange the four figures on one page. This is a lot trickier to do in LaTeX than it sounds. Having tried several methods, I think using `tikz` yet again to arrange the entire document works best. Examine the code of the final document: it uses `tikz` to position the individual figures relative to the document’s text area (with some additional ugly manual adjustments).

But first, let’s see the other two figures. They are a lot easier to draw. The top one is simply a circle, a line that goes from the left of the circle to the right (plus a few centimetres) and some text labels:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,circle,minimum width=1.5cm] (c) {};
    \draw (c.west) -- ($(c.east)+(3cm,0cm)$);
    \node[right=1mm of c,yshift=2mm] {\itshape Poussé};
    \node[right=1mm of c,yshift=-2mm] {\itshape Tiré};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The bottom is even easier: just two circles and two labels.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[accord/.style={draw,circle,minimum width=1.5cm}]
    \node[accord] (a) {};
    \node[accord,very thick,below=2mm of a] (b) {};
    \node[right=1mm of a] {\itshape Accord};
    \node[right=1mm of b] {\itshape Basse};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now to put it all together. There is one more thing: the title in the top left corner. I managed to get something similar using a `tabular` environment. This is how it looks:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% to set margins
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

% to input standalone documents within this one
\usepackage{standalone}
% packages and libraries used in included standalone documents
\usepackage{tikz,musicography}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,chains,matrix,positioning,shapes.multipart}

% to get tikz node for document body (-> current page text area)
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

% to get multirow cells in tables
\usepackage{multirow}

% to be able to vertically write text
\usepackage{rotating}


% title drawing command
\newcommand\drawtitle{%
    \noindent
    \bgroup% so that arraystretch only applies here
    \def\arraystretch{2}
    \begin{tabular}{l|p{6cm}}
        \multirow{4}{*}{%
            \begin{turn}{90}
                \Large\bfseries Plan de clavier
            \end{turn}
        }
        & {\Large\bfseries Système Le Tron / Laloy } \\[-2ex]
        %                                               ^^^^
        %       -2ex horizontal shift compensates for \Large
        & Tonalité: sol-do-altératíons. \\
        & Modèles à trois rangèes (33 boutons) \par et dix-huit
          basses \\
        & {} % empty row for vertical line to continue
    \end{tabular}
    \egroup
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} % get rid of page number

\drawtitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north]
        at ($(current page text area.north)+(0,-6)$)
        {\input{top}};
    \node[anchor=west]
        at ($(current page text area.north west)
             !.6! % align at a .6 ratio of the top and bottom
             (current page text area.south west)$)
        {\input{left}};
    \node[anchor=east]
        at ($(current page text area.north east)
             !.6!
             (current page text area.south east)$)
        {\input{right}};
    \node[anchor=south]
        at (current page text area.south)
        {\input{bottom}};

    \node at ($(current page text area.west)+(1,8)$)
        {\itshape Haut (graves)};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: picture of the output of the entire document]

Comment: Yes, my problem was mainely on the left side, but  your explaiantion and the idea to create separate classes helps a lot ! 

Do you have any idea to add the text on the top of the page ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with code to create the image on the left. It is not perfect, but it’s a start. What text do you mean? The ‘Systeme le tron’? I will try to add something for that too when I have time :-)

Comment: Oh Wow ! Thanks A lot ! If I could help you in return ... :) My question is how it is possible to combine theese two code in one file, like positionning one block in front to one other ?
Merci :)

Comment: I tried to put the things together but I did not manage to to it, I will wait for your answer ! Thanks

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I am working on my thesis and the deadline is ridiculously close so unfortunately I am unable to invest any more time in this at the moment. I do plan to get back to it later though!

Comment: I wish you the best with your Thesis :) I will see if I find the way otherwise I will wait :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi bp99, I still not solve my problem to put on the same A4 sheet the two part of code you put just few months ago.

Comment: Hi @zaord, I always felt like I had unfinished business here anyway :-) I updated my answer yet again, this time with a complete solution. There are still things to fix, but this should definitely get you started. I encourage you to play around with LaTeX and tikz yourself—it’s fun and you can do pretty much anything!